# Pyinstaller executable file not working properly

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe

I have a code that runs as expected on the IDE. It's a PyQt5 GUI application with some buttons to import an image then runs some Deep Learning algorithms on it and then generate some output with some log printed on the application. When I try to create an executable file via pyinstaller, the application first starts correctly but when I try to import the image and then run the treatment, the application restarts with no error messages. I even tried to execute the .exe file directly from cmd but again no errors were shown.

I have tried pyinstaller with different commands : --onefile, -onedir... I have checked the hidden libraries and made sure to import them but none of the .exe worked properly.

What may be causing the problem here since I have no errors showing or is there anyway to force print the errors ?